# how to send push notification for a specific device in windows phone 8 using azure

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I am developing windows phone application, For that I need to send push notification for a specific device or specific phone.
       I have succeed to send push notification for all device by one click, But I am unable to achieve to send a push notification for a specific phone. I have tried a lot i net but I can not find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you need get token or device id of your phone and save into server and one more thing, when you will register on Microsoft console, It provide us server key that key you need for server side. then you can get notification by MPNS.. thanks

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem**

Comment: Thanks for your response, It's working fine for android, But not for windows phone!! I tried both. for Windows phone I used MPSN and for android GCM.

Comment: Also I have a one more problem, How to get notification by neither not using GCM nor MPNS.

Comment: @Nisar one more way for push notification is parse notification.. check this[https://www.parse.com/user_session/new] .This is the best way to use notification. First you register your app and after you get two keys then with these you can get notification by parse.

Comment: Finally I got it through http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-phone-push-notifications-app-users/, thank you. I am not tried https://www.parse.com/user_session/new]

Comment: yes I tried it too, But I ve to connect it through Azure Mobile too.

Comment: very sad. What to do?

Comment: what to do mean ? you didn't get your answer ?

Comment: I got it by using MPNS or GCM. So my app is depending on Microsoft or Google. My org does not accept it.

Comment: you can use parse for notification.. just go that link its very simple and easy way to get notification

Comment: yes I tried and got notification when I test it, But I have to send notification when the user updated table in Azure DB, How can I connect Azure to parse. Is it possible? also I have to send notification not for all device,  For a particular device.

Comment: its not possible to connect Azure and parse. if you want to send notification to a particular user then when you add device token or id in database. you need to add one more parameter like phone number or other different id and put check in webservice.if that user match particular name then send notification to that user.

Comment: Is it possible to send notification by using their phone number or device id in android or windows phone. You done it?

Comment: Yes by device Id .. You can send